# x axis value displayed in line chart

Tags: jasper-reports

I have Line chart, in x axis i should display date in string format in full format, but i cant display when more no of values in x axis, for that i decided to display x axis values in vertical manner instead of horizontal , please suggest me. for ref attached image..

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sampl1" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="431d18d3-722a-4aaf-8207-da8bb0ea2fdd">
             <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
             <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
             <property name="ireport.y" value="51"/>
             <parameter name="whereClause" class="java.lang.String"/>
             <parameter name="bankLogo" class="java.lang.String"/>
             <parameter name="bankName" class="java.lang.String"/>
             <parameter name="fromDate" class="java.util.Date">
              <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
             </parameter>
             <parameter name="toDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
             <parameter name="noData" class="java.lang.String"/>
             <parameter name="userId" class="java.lang.String"/>
             <queryString>
              <![CDATA[select avg(jbase_user) as jbaseAvg,AVG(t24_user) as t24Avg,to_char(load_time, 'dd.Mon.yy HH24') as period
               from tmc_system_summary group by (to_char(load_time, 'dd.Mon.yy HH24'))]]>
             </queryString>
             <field name="jbaseavg" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
             <field name="t24avg" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
             <field name="period" class="java.lang.String"/>
             <background>
              <band splitType="Stretch"/>
             </background>
             <title>
              <band height="30" splitType="Stretch"/>
             </title>
             <pageHeader>
              <band height="67" splitType="Stretch">
               <staticText>
                <reportElement x="300" y="22" width="235" height="15" uuid="164831c1-9eff-4cf2-8706-331d28fdf431"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                 <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ System Summary Report]]></text>
               </staticText>
               <image>
                <reportElement x="12" y="3" width="161" height="30" uuid="513d2931-a2c7-4e54-bb86-188737502cae"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{bankLogo}]]></imageExpression>
               </image>
               <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="735" y="2" width="55" height="17" uuid="306ddad6-2b80-4abb-9893-859c59c8ede5"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                 <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
               </textField>
               <staticText>
                <reportElement x="700" y="2" width="30" height="17" uuid="c6fdbff7-45a5-464e-bcbf-d550b174452f"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                 <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Date:]]></text>
               </staticText>
               <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="40" width="58" height="14" uuid="5bd47ff1-6b81-428a-b7fd-50e777f70a22"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[From Date:]]></text>
               </staticText>
               <staticText>
                <reportElement x="160" y="40" width="58" height="14" uuid="a7605d9e-c0d1-4a31-8230-c73db35766d4"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[To Date:]]></text>
               </staticText>
               <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="80" y="40" width="70" height="14" uuid="faa13401-da98-4f06-ab43-5a1722d073f7"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}  != null ? $P{fromDate} :" "]]></textFieldExpression>
               </textField>
               <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="215" y="40" width="70" height="13" uuid="01fcdb71-820f-4ef1-9913-6ddcf36be2dc"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}  != null ? $P{toDate} : " "]]></textFieldExpression>
               </textField>
               <textField>
                <reportElement x="300" y="2" width="235" height="17" uuid="7eec4f6f-5bfd-4bb0-8888-8cad8d9d84ad"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                 <font fontName="Arial" size="14" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{bankName}]]></textFieldExpression>
               </textField>
               <staticText>
                <reportElement x="700" y="22" width="30" height="15" uuid="08ba273e-733d-4652-9f7a-83a51f7d78ca"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[By:]]></text>
               </staticText>
               <textField>
                <reportElement x="735" y="22" width="55" height="15" uuid="261308a5-7cef-42f8-8880-9d2c9cc5d5ae"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{userId}]]></textFieldExpression>
               </textField>
               <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="54" width="802" height="1" uuid="e17b6ea4-40fd-40ad-861f-a300f926d0e4"/>
               </line>
              </band>
             </pageHeader>
             <columnHeader>
              <band splitType="Stretch"/>
![enter image description here][1]           </columnHeader>
             <columnFooter>
              <band height="17" splitType="Stretch"/>
             </columnFooter>
             <pageFooter>
              <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
               <textField>
                <reportElement x="546" y="1" width="70" height="19" uuid="eeafb0de-dddb-4c9a-8a1d-942b65bf0a7f"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                 <font fontName="Arial" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
               </textField>
              </band>
             </pageFooter>
             <summary>
              <band height="392" splitType="Stretch">
               <lineChart>
                <chart>
                 <reportElement x="12" y="18" width="779" height="355" uuid="f696d665..
```

Answer (score 0):

By  this you can display  the x axis value in vertical ( topDown)

```
    <categoryAxisFormat labelRotation="90.0">
```

it will  work.